# How to add responce body in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

i am learning how to deploy swagger and openAPI.
i have a url as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/getDistance/12.496366,41.902782,-3.606997572,40.47416477
```

the user enters the coordinates and i receive response in a form of json file then i get the distance from the json file.

in swagger i have the below posted code and i would like to add

```
response body
```

i read about but i can not still figure it out

**code**:

```
parameters:
        - name: startAndEndCoords
          in: path
          description: Start and end GPS coordinates as comma separated values in terms of longitude and latitude respectively. 
          required: true
          schema:
            type: number
            format: float
          allowEmptyValue: false
      requestBody:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK. Successful operation
```

Comment: See [Describing Responses](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/), section "Response Body".

Comment: @Helen thanks i am using visual studio code and i use it to write swagger code. now i am done with swagger,,the question is how to see the results of swagger code ...should i just compile??please help me in this regard

Comment: What do you mean by "swagger code". Also looks like the path parameter should be an array of float. Also, If you want to check/validate your swagger JSON, then paste your JSON on editor.swagger.io and check if the UI loads up.